# How to allow all resources to one role in claims authorization without the need to add it to all the Web api Authorize attribute

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, role-base-authorization, claims-authentication

I have implemented claims based role authorization in my .net Core application.

Everything is working fine. I decorate my web api's like this and they work perfectly

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, GlobalEditor, RegionalEditor")]
```

The only problem is that the role "Admin" has access to absolutely everything in my application but I still have to specify it in the Authorize attribute of all the Web Api.

Is there any way to define somewhere centrally that if the role is "Admin" allow it everything and I do not have to specify it on all the web api?

Or is there any way to define the role hierarchy where I can define that if user is on the top role it has access to all the lower roles resources?

Comment: A policy-based authorization defined in Progam.cs will probably do the trick!

Comment: Have you tried to custom policy-based authorization? You can custom authenticate logic in it.